# Specifying h1 font family doesn't change font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have been stuck on this problem for awhile now, unable to find a solution through other sources. I am trying to change the font size for my h1 tag to oswald bold, I thought I knew how to do it but it doesn't want to work. heres my html...

```
<div id="Title1"><h1>Widest range of Holden parts in New Zealand</h1></div>
```

css...

```
h1 {
font-family:"Oswald Bold", bold, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-size: 60px; }
```

I have found a way of it working through editing the h1 rule directly through the dreamweaver but this creates a new stylesheet "stylesheet.css" which I don't need.

Any input is helpful, thanks.

Comment: Specify how you have defined the font in `@font-face`, where the font was obtained from, and how the font files were generated. Otherwise we cannot reproduce the problem situation, still less analyze it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put correctly and specify the generic family like this:

```
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
```

[more info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried a few combinations there but still couldn't get oswald to work. I have a feeling its not finding the font properly but I have no clue where to go from here :S. I've updated the css code if you want to have a look. Thanks :)

Comment: You also have to import the font. Try to put this link on your <header> code

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: Thanks tried that but didn't solve it, put it in the html <head></head> code right? I changed "oswald bold" to "oswald" which allowed me to have regular oswald which is a step in the right direction. If you have no other ideas I'm thinking the regular style may be good enough anyway. thanks :)

Comment: Inspect element to view wich font its using if you are using more than one css file it could be overwriting your custom font-family property. Or use put !IMPORTANT to your custom css rule like this:

font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif !IMPORTANT;

Comment: Yes in your <header><link href='fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700'; rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> </header> block code this import from google apis only imports the bold Oswald font, this only works if you have internet connection, obviusly =)
Remove the bold att from font-family rule this font type it's already bolded. You can import the normal font and set bolded with font-weigth:bold;

Comment: Awesome man, thanks a lot for the help. after seeing what regular oswald looks like I'm going to use that for my heading instead of bold. I've still learned a lot from your input though, thanks :).

Comment: If you think that this is the right answer, please, click check mark. Thank you.

Comment: Can't sorry need 15 reputation.